# Xen Network Bridging (or something else)

Tags: networking, virtualization, linux-networking, xen, xenserver

I'm trying to achieve the following: [Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34xre.png)

Question:
How can I do what's in red? I know how to add a network interface when it's about a physical interface. But how can I create a virtual network interface(s) that I would use it to connect only two VMs to one another?

Comment: Without knowing how to do this in Xen: create a new bridge xenbr1 and add vifs corresponding to vm02-eth2

Comment: check there for info; https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_Networking#Attaching_virtual_devices_to_the_appropriate_bridge

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how to do this in Xen: create a new bridge xenbr1 and add vifs corresponding to vm02-eth2 and vm02-eth0 to it. If Xen's bridging scripts are not flexible enough to do this you can use a dummy interface on the host: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152331/how-can-i-create-a-virtual-ethernet-interface-on-a-machine-without-a-physical-ad

Comment: On XenServer by default the network stack is via vSwitch, the OP will need to issue 'xe-switch-network-backend bridge' to switch back to Linux's based networkstack to try your tip.

Comment: Is there any more straightforward way to do this? Possibly through Xen Center

Comment: @user376989 no, through xencenter it was my tip that I erased